# iCloud password Chrome extension sets focus on first input during localhost dev

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, localhost, web-development, icloud

I recently installed the [iCloud password sync extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-passwords/pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj) on Windows.  I do web development and when I run my localhost environment it auto-focuses the first input it finds.  This messes me up because I'm working with form validation and this registers as a user input event.

Is there a way to disable this (or any) extension for `localhost` URL's?  Enabling/disabling the entire extension is a pain since it requires 2FA to re-enable every time.

it also injects some HTML into my project, and throws some errors in my console, which is super unhelpful during development.

[image: iCloud passwords extension throws errors and injects HTML into localhost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen suggestions to create multiple profiles and switch between them, which would work but would be aggravating because that's a lot of setup and I typically switch between personal and work things throughout the day.

I've found no easy solution to this, but I found something that works for now.  **I simply open my `localhost` development stuff in an Incognito window**.  This by default doesn't load any extensions, but I can choose which ones to allow if I need any for development.  I'd rather just keep a single window with all my tabs in it, but having two windows (one incognito, one regular) isn't so bad.